# Why does 'global' not work within an 'if'?

Tags: python-3.x

Why in a function when trying to use `global` within an in if to condition it this still works even if the `if` does not meet the condition?

Example:

```
>>> x=4
>>>
>>> def show():
...     a=10
...     if a==15:
...        global x
...     x=22
...
>>> x
4
>>>
>>> show()
>>> x
22
>>>
```

Is there any way to condition a global?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `global` keyword affects the whole function. It's more a parser directive than some executable code that tells the Python parser to interpret the identifiers as global. That says, it doesn't matter if it's put inside an `if` or `for` block, as long as the parser sees it, it will take effect in the whole function starting from the line it's on.

[Python documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global):

> The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block.

#### Is there any way to condition a global?

With that above, I'd imagine that there's no direct way to achieve this. I'd suggest that you use a different name for the variable if you don't want it to be global, and assign to the global variable when needed.

Answer (score 1):

So the difference between these examples is where I see the confusing behavior:

```
x=4

def show():
    a = 10
    if a == 15:
        global x
    x = 22
    print(x)

show()
# print statement: 22

x
Out[31]: 22
```

And this:

```
x=4

def show():
    x = 22
    print(x)

show()
# print statement: 22

x
Out[33]: 4
```

The best example I can provide of how to mix and match `local`, `nonlocal`, and `global` is based on the Classes docs [Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) example.

```
def scope_test():
    def do_local():
        x = 22
        print("in do_local:", x)

    def do_nonlocal():
        nonlocal x
        x = 22
        print("in do_nonlocal:", x)

    def do_global():
        global x
        x = 22
        print("in do_global:", x)

    x = 4
    do_local()
    print("After local assignment:", x)
    x = 4
    do_nonlocal()
    print("After nonlocal assignment:", x)
    x = 4
    do_global()
    print("After global assignment:", x)

scope_test()
print("In global scope:", x)
```

Result:

```
in do_local: 22
After local assignment: 4
in do_nonlocal: 22
After nonlocal assignment: 22
in do_global: 22
After global assignment: 4
In global scope: 22
```

From their text (and replace `spam` with `x`):

> Note how the local assignment (which is default) didn’t change
>   scope_test’s binding of spam. The nonlocal assignment changed
>   scope_test’s binding of spam, and the global assignment changed the
>   module-level binding.
>
> You can also see that there was no previous binding for spam before
>   the global assignment.

To set this up with conditionals you can try something like this:

```
def scope_test(x,condition):
    def do_local():
        x = 22
        print("in do_local:", x)

    def do_nonlocal():
        nonlocal x
        x = 22
        print("in do_nonlocal:", x)

    def do_global():
        global x
        x = 22
        print("in do_global:", x)

    if condition==15:
        do_global()
        print("After global assignment:", x)
    elif condition==10:
        do_local()
        print("After local assignment:", x)
    else:
        do_nonlocal()
        print("After nonlocal assignment:", x)

value = 4
all_conditions = [5,10,15]
for condition in all_conditions:
    scope_test(value,condition)
    print("In global scope:", x,"\n")
```

Output:

```
in do_nonlocal: 22
After nonlocal assignment: 22
In global scope: 22 

in do_local: 22
After local assignment: 4
In global scope: 22 

in do_global: 22
After global assignment: 4
In global scope: 22
```

additional note: as iBug's answer cites from the documentation:

> The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block.